# Who is responsible for updating the Java API and how can other individuals contribute?

Tags: java, api, oracle

I made a search on google to find out who are the people in Oracle responsible for updating the Java API in other words who are those responsible for adding new classes and methods to the API and updating the Java Documentation.

I could not find an answer to this question which leads me to the next question, what if I had some classes that are not found in the API which I wished to share with others, how do I get Oracle to add those classes for me?

Comment: Unless you are a represented by a massive corporation or working for Oracle the answer is you probably can't. Create a library and distribute that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you'd like to suggest a feature or report a bug to Oracle, you can do so via their [bug report and feature request page](http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/index.jsp).

Java's implementation is now managed via the OpenJDK as the official reference implementation. If you want to [contribute](http://openjdk.java.net/contribute/), you'll need to follow this path, summarized from the page linked:

1. Find something to work on. You seem to have this step complete.
2. Discuss your intended change(s) with others on the project
3. Submit a patch. You'll need to know how to use [Mercurial](http://hginit.com/) and how to do [unit testing](http://openjdk.java.net/jtreg/) in order to complete this step.
4. You'll then need to get a sponsor who is already working as a JDK 8 update or JDK 9 committer. They'll evaluate your work and work with you to address deficiencies.
5. Your code gets incorporated into the JDK. Or not, mostly likely not. They recommend making sure that you really know what you are doing before you start working on this kind of a project. They also recommend hacking against the JDK 9 sources before you try to start submitting features.

All told what you ask is doable but *very* difficult. A better option might be to devise a library or framework that houses your classes and then put it up on Github or Bitbucket and try to attract interest in usage and improvement.

Comment: I'll add to this that the landscape is changing - please join the adoptopenjdk.java.net project which is a new group within OpenJDK to help onboard new folks and contributions.